# IIS Application Request Routing (ARR) reverse proxy rewrite to Apache with authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, reverse-proxy, http-basic-authentication

I'd need to rewrite an IIS site (using the ARR proxy method to keep the original URL) to another one which is hosted on an Apache 2 server. The Apache server requests a basic authentication. The problem is when I try to log in to the Apache auth through the IIS reverse proxy it won't work and I get the auth popup in loop. I guess there's a problem with IIS transmitting the auth informations. Could someone tell if there's a known configuration for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Without solution I allowed the access to the IIS servers on the Apache with an "Allow from"